# How to produce a λ without curls in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex

When plotting a graph with `ggplot`, using `labs(x=expression(paste(lambda))` produces the following:

[image]

However, in the article where I need this graph to be in, writing $\lambda$ in LaTeX produces a lambda looking as follows:

[image]

As you can see, they look different. How can I change the lambda produced by R, so that my lambdas look the same everywhere in the article?

Comment: Have a look at the `latex2exp` package to plot mathematical symbols 
in `latex` style: https://github.com/stefano-meschiari/latex2exp

Comment: I have tried that as well but unfortunately it did not work. I used `labs(x=TeX("$\\lambda$")` and it produced the same lambda in R.

Comment: `labs(x = "\u03BB")`?

Comment: @Lyngbakr, it gave me a warning and  the end result was '..' under the x axis. The warning: `In grid.Call(L_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)) :
  conversion failure on 'λ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <ce>`

Comment: @ksm001 I can't reproduce that. I'll post my MCVE below, as I can't include a picture in the comments. Can you run that code in a fresh session and tell me if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best LaTeX compatibility, use `library(tikzDevice)`. This gets *identical* fonts etc. etc. to whatever you're using in LaTeX. For maximal satisfaction/integration, you can embed these tikz files directly into a knitr/Sweave file (see [here](http://www.rexamine.com/2013/04/my-global-knitr-settings-with-tikzdevice-graphics/), [here](http://iltabiai.github.io/tips/latex/2015/09/15/latex-tikzdevice-r.html), [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/graphics/) for more info ...)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tikzDevice)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

g <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
g <- g + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 50))
## dollar signs for LaTeX math mode, double-\ to make R happy
g <- g + xlab("$\\lambda$")
```

Now print to a tikz file

```
tikz("tikz1.tex", standAlone=TRUE)
print(g)
dev.off()
```

Convert to a PDF (and from there to a PNG, so I can post the results here)

```
system("pdflatex tikz1.tex")
system("evince tikz1.pdf")   ## look at it with my system's PDF viewer
system("convert tikz1.pdf tikz1.png")  ## ImageMagick
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

g <- ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
g <- g + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 50))
g <- g + xlab("\u03BB")
print(g)
```

[image]

Comment: it gave me the same warning as before and printed two dots instead of lambda: `20: In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... : conversion failure on 'λ' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <bb>`. What could this mean?

Comment: @ksm001 Are you running this in a plain old R script?

Comment: yes, the answer by Ben seems to have worked for me at least. Maybe it has to do with some encoding issue on my computer.

Comment: @ksm001 Perhaps. Anyway, I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else in the future.